# Spring Boot & ActiveMQ Artemis: NoClassDefFoundError during start of application

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-artemis

When trying to create a Spring Boot Java application with ActiveMQ Artemis I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'artemisConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration]: Factory method 'artemisConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/QueueConfiguration
```

From the above exception I have difficult to understand what config might be missing or is it something else? I am using Spring Boot 2.7.3.

It is implemented to the letter as described in the [this guide](http://www.masterspringboot.com/messaging/artemismq/jms-messaging-with-spring-boot-and-artemis-mq/) (native and embedded).

Comment: Use below to debug further http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/QueueConfiguration
```

This means that the JVM can't find this class. This class is in the `artemis-commons` module. You need to put this on your application's classpath.

Comment: Thanks but it actually did not solve the problem

Comment: You still see a `NoClassDefFoundError` even with `artemis-commons` on the classpath? Or are you getting a different error now?

Comment: Yeah same exception still

Comment: If you're still getting the same exception that indicates `artemis-commons` is not, in fact, on the classpath.